# get the velocity value of a swipe?

Tags: javascript, swipe, hammer.js

hammer.js (http://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-swipe/) checks the velocity of the swipe, I wonder how to get this value in order to determent how big the margin-left of my element #visitContent should be and get a smoother swipe.

html

```
    <section id="visits">
            <div id='visitsContent'>
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Javascript

```
var visits = document.getElementById('visits');
var mc = new Hammer(visits, {velocity:0.80});

mc.on("swipeleft", function(ev) {
    $('#visitsContent').css({
    marginLeft : '-=200px'
})
});
mc.on("swiperight", function(ev) {
    $('#visitsContent').css({
    marginLeft : '+=200px'
})
});
```

sass

```
    #visits
    width: 100%
    padding: 0px
    border-bottom: none
    background-color: $backgroundColorSecond
    margin-bottom: 10px
    margin-left: -20px
    #visitsContent
        div
            width: 180px
            height: 180px
            float: left
            margin-left: 5px
            background-color: green
            color: black
            text-align: center
```

there is also a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/mL911mqn/

Answer (score 2):

Judging from your jsfiddle it looks like you're using the pan gesture now instead of the swipe gesture. So in your pan event handler, you should be able to access the drag velocity like this:

```
function panGestureHandler(ev){
    var velocity = ev.gesture.velocity;
    var velocityX = ev.gesture.velocityX;
    var velocityY = ev.gesture.velocityY;
    console.log("horizontal drag speed = " + velocityX);
}
```